# Why reading a line from stdin prevents reading from stdin.buffer in Python

Tags: python

Why reading a line from stdin prevents reading from stdin.buffer in Python

Snippet:

```
import sys

a = sys.stdin.readline()
b = sys.stdin.buffer.readline()

print("A :: {}".format(a))
print("B :: {}".format(b))
```

executing with `<` operator to provide a file as stdin.
`python script.py < text.txt`

Output:

```
A :: Line_1
B :: b''
```

File:

```
Line_1
Line_2
Line_3
```

Why B does not print Line_2 .?

---

**UPDATE:**

the snippet with the same configuration but with a change in the sequence

```
import sys

b = sys.stdin.buffer.readline()
a = sys.stdin.readline()

print("A :: {}".format(a))
print("B :: {}".format(b))
```

OUTPUT:

```
A :: Line_2
B :: Line_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from stdin directly will consume the underliying bytes buffer stream.
How much of it will be consumed is part of the internal implementation, and is not controlled by the user - it is however, logical that reading from the text contents from stdin will at least consume a couple more bytes from the buffer (and for efficiency reasons, could consume a lot more).

Few people will hit this problem because it makes little sense to try to read from stdin in both ways in the same application - you will either interact with text data, or you will interact with binary data there. (And in this case, all you have to do, if you have some text among your binary data is to handle it manually, and explicitly apply charset decoding and end-of-line translation on your Python code).

In other words: the internal implementation consumes the buffer ahead of what is read for its translation.

The right thing to do: choose to interact with either the buffer or the text layer, and interact only with that for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), the `buffer` object is designed for use with binary data, not text:

> **Note** To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the underlying binary buffer object. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc').
>   However, if you are writing a library (and do not control in which context its code will be executed), be aware that the standard streams may be replaced with file-like objects like io.StringIO which do not support the buffer attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Mikah, but the post still does not answer the question. Why the stdin.readline() did not fetch the 2nd line from stdin.?

Comment: Your question was why reading a line prevents getting a value from reading the buffer.  If that's not what you're after, please edit your question.

Comment: It is still the same. I think I did not get why the stdin.buffer.readline() returned empty string instead of `Line_2`